# react map doesnt update (array of components with props) when props update

Tags: reactjs

I have this state variable installpvcomponent that is an array of components that is updated when i click a button on my react page :

```
setInstallpvcomponent(installpvcomponent => {
    var newComponent = (
      <SimulationInstallpvsup
        key={index}
        installPvsup={props.installPvsup}
        handleOnChange={props.handleOnChange}
        inputPlaceholder={inputPlaceholder}
        labelClasses={labelClasses}
        inputClasses={inputClasses}
        totalOfNumbers={totalOfNumbers}
        parentLabelInputDiv={parentLabelInputDiv}
        listeChampsError={props.listeChampsError}
        reflist={reflist}
        index={index}
        handleButtonDel={handleButtonDel}
      />
    );
    return [...installpvcomponent, newComponent];
  });
```

I am then mapping the Installpvcomponent array in my react page:

```
   <div id="installpvsup">
             {installpvcomponent.map((component,index) => (
            <div key={component.key}>
            {component}
            </div>
          ))}
          
          </div>
```

However, when reflist prop is updated, it doesnt update in my page. I have done a console.log inside newComponent to check if the value update and it doesnt.

How can I resolve this?

I have tried to change the keys of the component with Math.random(), i have tried to use React.Fragment instead of div in the page.
I have tried to ask chatGPT.
Edit: when i console.log reflist in the main code, it does update of course.

Comment: What's the relationship between setInstallpvcomponent and installpvcomponent?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it's a state variable...
actually i will update the post because i have tested something and i want to understand how it works to propagate changes in state variables

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution :

I map my components on an array of data which is declared as a state variable and I update this array with a `useEffect` :

```
const [installpvdata, setInstallpvdata] = useState([]);

const updateInstallpvdata = () => {
const updatedData = installpvdata.map((item) => {
  return {
    ...item,
    installPvsup: props.installPvsup, 
    reflist: reflist, 
  };
});

 useEffect(() => {
updateInstallpvdata();
}, [props.installPvsup,reflist]);
```

I then map my generic component based on this data array instead of an array of components.

```
<div id="installpvsup">
             {installpvdata.map((item,index) => (
            <div>
                  <SimulationInstallpvsup
                    key={item.key}
                    installPvsup={item.installPvsup}
                    handleOnChange={props.handleOnChange}
                    inputPlaceholder={inputPlaceholder}
                    labelClasses={labelClasses}
                    inputClasses={inputClasses}
                    totalOfNumbers={totalOfNumbers}
                    parentLabelInputDiv={parentLabelInputDiv}
                    listeChampsError={props.listeChampsError}
                    myKey={item.key}
                    handleButtonDel={handleButtonDel}
                    reflist={item.reflist}
                    />

            </div>
          ))}
          </div>
```